# What is the scope of class definition in DM script?

Tags: multithreading, dm-script

I have defined a thread derived class at the beginning of the script:

```
    class procthread : thread
    { 
......      

        object init( object self)   
        {   
...
        }   

        void RunThread( object self )   
        {     
.....    
        }

    }
```

and then MyDialog class, which is supposed to use this thread:

```
Class MyDialog: UIFrame

{
object wrkthread
.....
    TagGroup CreateMyDialog(Object self, number nref)
    {
........
        btn0=DLGCreatePushButton("+","DoBut0").DLGIdentifier("#PushB0")
        wrkthread=alloc(procthread) ////<----- works

        return DialogTG
    }


    Object Init(Object self, number nref) return self.super.Init(self.CreateMyDialog(nref))

    Void DoBut0(Object self) 
        {
        wrkthread=alloc(procthread) ////<---- does not work
        } 
}
```

To the logic of the script the thread should be allocated and activated every time the button is pressed. 
However "wrkthread=alloc(procthread)" called in the on_button_pressed handler throws an exception "Cannot find class 'procthread'". At the same time the same call from Init function works nicely and the thread runs.

What is the problem here? I cannot believe that class definitions are visible within the main thread only, this makes no sense.

If I make a mistake, could you please correct?
If this is a feature - how to get around it?

Comment: You might also want to look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25502045/1302888)

Comment: Alternative solution would be to install the class as a libary first, but that is not a very nice solution. I'm just mentioning it for completeness sake.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "How to get around it" - essentially your own example shows you "the workaround" already, doesnt' it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, UI  actions are (and have to, if you think of it) run on the DM-Application main thread. Hence the DoBut0 action acts on a different thread than the one from your script. So in a way, yes, launching a script interpreter keeps the script code only in "its" scope, and separately created threads (like UI actions) do not know about it.

One way around it is to have your class keep a member object of the class you want to execute from the button and so forces it to stay in scope. (Which is your "working" solution above.) If you need a "new" object with each UI action, you can achieve this by cloning the object instead of allocating it in the member function. (i.e. the member object is just a 'template' object)

Here is another example:

```
Class AClass
{
    AClass(Object self)     Result("\n object AClass created: ID=" + self.ScriptObjectGetID() )     // Just for debugging info 
    ~AClass(Object self)    Result("\n object AClass destroyed: ID=" + self.ScriptObjectGetID())    // Just for debugging info . Check no memory leak!!

    void AAction(Object self) Result("\t ACTION A")
}

Class BClass : UIFrame
{
    BClass(Object self)     Result("\n object BClass created: ID=" + self.ScriptObjectGetID() )     // Just for debugging info 
    ~BClass(Object self)    Result("\n object BClass destroyed: ID=" + self.ScriptObjectGetID())    // Just for debugging info . Check no memory leak!!

    Object keepOtherOBJ

    void CreateOtherObject(Object self) 
    {
        result("\nAllocation prepare")
        keepOtherOBJ = Alloc(AClass)
        result("\nAllocation done")
    }

    void CallOtherAction(Object self) 
    {
        Result("\n Calling other action:")
        keepOtherOBJ.AAction()
    }

    void ButtonAction(Object self)
    {
        Result("\n Pressing button")
        //  self.CreateOtherObject()                // ==> THIS IS NOT working. Button action is called separately in memory which doesn't know about "Class A"
        self.CallOtherAction()


        // Or you may want to clone the "template" and run it like this
        keepOtherObj.Clone().AAction()
    }

    Object InitAndShow(Object self)
    {

        TagGroup DLGtg,DLGitems
        DLGtg = DLGCreateDialog("Test",DLGitems)
        DLGitems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreatePushButton("Other Class Action","ButtonAction") )
        self.Init(DLGtg)

        self.CreateOtherObject()                // ==> THIS IS working. The object is created and kept as local member

        self.Display("Test")
    }
}

// MAIN script
{
    Object BObject = Alloc(BClass)
    BObject.InitAndShow()   
}
```